# Wifi won't enter working net after hard reboot

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless

I rebooted the hard way after my system jammed again because FF eats all the ram. (that's a different problem)

I've always gotten away with it, but not this time.

The system came up ok BUT it absolutely refuses to log onto the local house wifi net. I know the net is ok as the Windows box I'm writing this on is on it right now.

I deleted the connection and rentered the password but it will not go on. `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` says everything is turned on.

I know this is my fault but I'd really like to get back on the net. The machine is a Toshiba Satellite.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you *see* wireless networks or *connect* to a wireless network? It's an important difference.

Comment: Other than purging and reinstalling the network manager, I don't have an idea for your question. HOWEVER, I WOULD recommend using ALT-SysRq R E I S U B next time you encounter a hang preventing you from shutting down "gracefully". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: ^ That is amazing. I've always wondered what the system request key was for.

Comment: Can you open a terminal, run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`, then leave that running, try connecting to your network, then post back the results of the terminal?  (Note - if you're worried about the Mac addresses showing up, best just blank them out before posting).

Answer (score 2):

Some troubleshooting steps :

Open a terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`, then try connecting to your terminal.  On a successful authentication, you should see something like this :

```
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.560236] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.560242] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.560245] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583441] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583446]     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583449]     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583452]     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583454]     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583457]     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 12 21:45:37 GroovyTosh kernel: [19329.583459]     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 12 21:45:38 GroovyTosh kernel: [19330.677366] wlan0: authenticate with <removed MAC> (try 1)
Feb 12 21:45:38 GroovyTosh kernel: [19330.678697] wlan0: authenticated
Feb 12 21:45:38 GroovyTosh kernel: [19330.678727] wlan0: associate with <removed MAC> (try 1)
Feb 12 21:45:38 GroovyTosh kernel: [19330.680336] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <removed MAC> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Feb 12 21:45:38 GroovyTosh kernel: [19330.680339] wlan0: associated
```

So at least you'll see if you're failing to authenticate (check your WEP/WPA key), or associate (a problem with the router, perhaps).

It might also be worth monitoring the syslog directly, in case this is DHCP related, for example.  Just use `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, perhaps in a second terminal (although much of what is written in kern.log is written to syslog to be honest).